# VMware Automation very slow

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, vmware, automation

My PC configuration is i7 3.4 GHZ, 32gb of RAM and With SATA 7200 RPM HDD .. 
My initial Plan was to automate 10 VM's on this machine , but when i am doing that VMware gets hanged. My Guest VM do not use lots of Power they are basically Windows XP 512 mb ram with single processor allocated

PS: I am Checking the task manager for system utilization for processor and ram its very low around 10 -12 % but for HDD its using almost 100%. Do you think its a issue with HDD and if it is then what is solution for this problem .

Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful to know which product of VMware are you using. Also number of CPU cores is an important information too. And yes, HDD could certainly be the weak point. Do you start the machines in parallel or sequentially? (Wait till a machine is fully booted before starting next one.)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the I/O throughput of 10 VMs on a single HDD is killing your setup.

The solution would be using external storage, and use RAID (the RAID type of choice greatly depends on the VMs activity -write intensive vs. read intensive). If this is a home (or non-professional) setting, maybe NAS would be enough. For a professional setup, this is definitely not the appropriate hardware.

Comment: so what should be the appropriate setup according to you . See 10vm are my requirement .. and they should be running and performing some tasks in parallel

Comment: For a professional environment: two physical servers (Xeon or similar) with external storage, FC SAN.